# How to read only specified columns only with PhpExcel Codeplex

Tags: php

I am using php library from

http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

for reading .xls, .xlsx and .csv .

And i have to also work with large size files. And it gives out of memory issues. i have already increased the memory limit in php.ini.

I am not sure but as i have learnt the memory consumed size is depends on the number of cells in the excel.

And in my excel files the no. of rows are very large but i have to read only 5-6 columns. So i just want to read only those specified columns so that the blank columns do not consumes the memory for the script.

So my question is that how can i read only specified column by using this library.

e.g :- If i want to read only first five columns.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use phpexcel with 10MB file, it works fine. but however if you want to specify range you can go to http://www.contao-docs.org/docs/PHPExcel/html/index.html. I think you need

```
PHPExcel_Worksheet::rangeToArray
```